# Update many(multiple) rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having some problem with update. When I got one record in the database, then it works correctly, but when I got more than 1, it didn't work correctly.

Here is code :

```
UPDATE rozl 
SET amountAfter = (SELECT amountBefore - (amount + destroyed) FROM rozl)
```

Table looks like

```
  id    number   amountBefore    amount    destroyed    amountAfter
   1         3            100        30           20             50
   2         4            50         10           3             NULL
```

When I'm running the update, I expect `amountAfter` to get fill with value.

The error which I'm getting :

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Then I run this `Select` from update, I get 2 rows which are correct but I can't update it.

Output from select is :

```
   1   50
   2   37
```

As I said, it's correct but i had no idea how to write it in update.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need the subquery:

```
update rozl
set amountAfter= amountBefore - (amount + destroyed)
```

As commented, you do need the parentheses as the order of operations matter.

Comment: You might want to add parentheses as specified in the question. In the first case you'd have 100 - 30 + 20, which is 90 rather than 50. Best of luck.

Comment: Oh my god, im so dumb :( ! Thanks a lot, i just add ().